# Angularjs how to share data between two directive via $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives.There is a asynchronized function in link in each directive like `$http` or `ngResource`. I want to click button A to get data from backend via directive A, then change the data in directive B and its view.

I try to use a data service with `$boastcast` as most people do to share data between directive A and B, and use `$apply` to update the view. But I frequently get the inprog error. So what is the best way to solve it out?

Comment: Hi. Please post your code

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. May not even  need a broadcast and most likely don't need $apply()

Answer (score 0):

That error ocuur when you are runnig `$scope.$apply`. When you try to manually run the digest loop that is alread runing then this exception will occur

So check if digest is running before use apply

`if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  $scope.$apply()
}`

Comment: Probably it will work, but today it is recognized as bad habit. First you have dependency from $scope which we should try to avoid. Secondly, $$phase is internal Angular thing. It could be resolve with wrapping code with wrapping code im $timeout instead of $apply. $timeout will call digest cycle im safe way, only when cycle is not running already.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping code with $apply, try to inject $timeout and wrap your code with $timeout.  It will run digest cycle im safe way, only when cycle is not running already.